# How to retrieve data from Firebase database and show the values in Google map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my database, I have values about location for each persons like that [database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38aP6.png) and I want to retrieve data and show in the map. How get get and show? I created an `ArrayList` and details class constuctor for get a values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question and post some [mcve]. So, that we can easily understand what do you have tried so far and problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference locationsRef = rootRef.child("Locations");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String latitude = ds.child("Latitude").getValue(String.class);
            String longitude = ds.child("Longitude").getValue(String.class);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(String.valueOf(latitude), String.valueOf(longitude));
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("My Marker");
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
locationsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

But I strongly recommend you, to store the values for the `latitude` and `longitude` as `doubles` and not as strings.

Comment: thanks, when one location update in firebase, there are two or depend on update times, marker have show same device each times on map . (i used ds.child("Email").getValue(String.class for the title ) and some time i have four marker for same title . can you give idea for slove this

Comment: If the marker is moving, then just remove the marker from an earlier position, right?

Comment: please can you give a sample code? it will be a great help thnks

Comment: The initial question is `How to retrieve data from Firebase database and show the values in Google map?` and for that I just gave an answer. If you have other questions, you should make you own attempt given the information in the comment or ask another question if something else comes up. So in case of something comes up, in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: okey, actually your answer be a helped to me thnks, i'll post a another for that thank for your help